# Unable to Load Library 'virt': libvirt.so

Tags: java

I'm working on Ubuntu and using Netbeans. My code is trying to connect to the libvirt host "qemu+ssh://IPaddress/system". The development environment and the service environment is different. The output-jar file I put on the service environment but apparently I hit below error when rebooting the service. I already added the jna-3.2.5.jar and the libvirt-0.5.1.jar on to the path folder of my service environment.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to
load library 'virt': libvirt.so: cannot open shared object file: No
such file or directory 
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:164) 
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:375)  
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:360)  
at org.libvirt.jna.Libvirt.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.libvirt.Library.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.libvirt.Connect.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

What else I have missed?

Comment: which service ? where ? how ?

Comment: describe more about your code ??

Comment: I'm working on Ubuntu and using Netbeans. My code is trying to connect to the libvirt host "qemu+ssh://IPaddress/system"

Comment: It's best to edit your question and include the information there, so that everyone can see it more easily. :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response.
Apparently, I have to install libvirt package on to my service environment, and the error will be gone. I hope it will help other's problem as well.